# NoClassDefFoundError HibernateJpaVendorAdapter.java while deploying in wildfly 10.1

Tags: wildfly-10, hibernate-entitymanager

I am finding it really hard to figure out the cause of the error. I have been getting this error during LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean creation in my config. I have attached the Error I get. I am using 
Springboot
Wildfly 10.1
Hibernate-search

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/HibernateException
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter.<init>(HibernateJpaVendorAdapter.java:66)
    at com.mas.dhcpr3.config.Appconfig.entityManagerFactory(Appconfig.java:42)
    at com.mas.dhcpr3.config.Appconfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b1fb2a11.CGLIB$entityManagerFactory$3(<generated>)
    at com.mas.dhcpr3.config.Appconfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b1fb2a11$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$67e8e45c.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358)
    at com.mas.dhcpr3.config.Appconfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b1fb2a11.entityManagerFactory(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 39 more
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.HibernateException from [Module "deployment.newdhcpr3-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:198)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
    ... 51 more
```

The POM.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>newdhcpr3</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <groupId>com.mas.dhcpr3</groupId>
    <name>Spring Boot Data JPA Sample</name>
    <description>Spring Boot Data JPA Sample</description>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <url>http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/</url>
    <organization>
        <name>Pivotal Software, Inc.</name>
        <url>http://www.spring.io</url>
    </organization>
    <properties>
        <main.basedir>${basedir}/../..</main.basedir>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <thymeleaf.version>3.0.3.RELEASE</thymeleaf.version>
        <thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>2.2.1</thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <!-- Your own application should inherit from spring-boot-starter-parent -->
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                 <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                  <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions> 
        </dependency>
        <!-- Search-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.0.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.7</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

                <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>com/mas/dhcpr3/newdhcpr3/data/*/*/*.java</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The bean code

```java
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
  LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
  em.setDataSource(dataSource());
  em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.mas.dhcpr3.Entities" });
  // em.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
  em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());
  JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
  em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);


  return em;
}
```

Can any of you please help. I dont get any compilation error, and i can see the JPAVendorAdapter class in spring-orm 4.3 jar in my packaged war file. I was guessing that it could be because of the conflict in Wildfly's internal version. But i couldnt find any spring-orm  jars. I am completely lost. can  any of you please help Thank you

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. After packaging the war, i tried deploying it into my application server, which ended up with this error. My server is wildfly10.1

Comment: It looks like it's trying to load Hibernate from your deployment. Do you have a `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` in your deployment?

Comment: Hi James, Thanks for replying. Yes you are right, I am not using  jboss-deployment-structure.xml, I will try to use that and update you on the results. Thanks again

Comment: Finally fixed the issue, by copying the latest hibernate-search and hibernate-orm into the wildfly modules folder, and configuring them in the persistence.xml That resolved the incompatibility. Thanks James